# @HostListener in Angular 2 directive is not allowing to manipulate elements

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to write an Angular 2 directive to recreate functionality of the Foundation Zurb Accordion component. I have tried to do something that I thought was simple. I have created a directive and added a HostListener to listen for click events. However anything that I do within the HostListener seems to be ignored apart from manipulation of the host element itself. I was just trying to select the parent element of the clicked accordion link and set its content div to display block (see code below). Am I missing something fundamental?

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {Directive} from "@angular/core/src/metadata/directives";

@Directive({
  selector: '[sdAccordion]'
})

export class SdAccordionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @HostListener("document:click", ['$event']) onClick(e){
    var clickedEl = e.target;
    var classList = clickedEl.classList;
    if(classList.contains('accordion-item')){
      //This comes back as null but if I try the selector in debig mode in console it works
      var contentEl = clickedEl.parentNode.querySelector('.accordion-content');
      //this console.log never gets executed
      console.log(contentEl);

      if(classList.contains('is-active')){
        classList.remove('is-active'); //this works
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(contentEl, 'display', 'block'); //this does not work
      }else{
        classList.add('is-active');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(contentEl, 'display', 'none');
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
  <ul class="accordion" sdAccordion>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        I would start in the open state, due to using the `is-active` state class.
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        I would start in the open state, due to using the `is-active` state class.
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use @hostbinding to change element host state